# Shipyard, how to add "context" or "base path"?

Tags: apache

I'm trying to setup a Shipyard server (controller) at work, but I've run into an issue.  The server is up and running, which I can confirm with curl just fine.  And we've configured Apache httpd to do forwarding, as we intend for the machine running Shipyard to not be directly accessible.  So basically we setup a rule for Apache that incoming requests to /shipyard map to :8080/ which is where it's being served from.  So the problem is that I need a way to tell Shipyard to remap "/" to "/shipyard".  When I try to go to the Shipyard homepage, nothing on the page loads correctly.  For example, Shipyard tried to load some js files:

/app/images/images.module.js

But to work with our forwarding, it needs to try to load:

/shipyard/app/images/images.module.js

With the kinds of servers I'm used to working with, this would normally be done by specifying a "context" or "base path" in your server config for it to serve from.  I'm wondering how to do something similar for Shipyard?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is already a github issue for this exact scenario:

https://github.com/shipyard/shipyard/issues/972